# Restricting sub-query to 2 arguments in same row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It's been hours that I've been searching for a solution (books, internet, etc) and can't find anything. Here's my problem:

I got a table of items being tagged by 2 criteria: let's name them crit1 and crit2. For each of the items I can have for crit1 and crit2 the following int example values (criteria1,criteria2): (1,5) (5,2) (4,7) (8,6), etc.

In another table I store users that are subscribed to some of these items filtered by the above criteria. Let's say that user_id 1 is subscribed to the following item type (criteria1, criteria2): (1,5) (2,7). When I make my query to fetch the items that user 1 is subscribed to, I get the items tagged with (1,5) (2,7) but also (1,7) or (2,5). The SQL Select query is making cross-comparisons between each row.

Generally, I would like to know how to make a query that is filtered from more than 1 field in the same row (no cross-row allowed).

I tried to use JOINS to sort the problem but I can't link criteria1 and criteria2 in the same JOIN. I have to use 2 JOINS and that makes them independent (and the cross-comparison between criteria1 and criteria2 will happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND operator in ON clause for JOIN:

```
SELECT i.* FROM subscriptions s
JOIN items i
ON i.crit1 = s.crit1 AND i.crit2 = s.crit2
WHERE s.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

without seeing the rest of the structure specifically, I'll give it a shot like...

```
select
      i.itemid,
      i.itemDescription,
      s.subscriberName
   from
      items i
         join Subscribers s
            on i.category1 = s.category1
           AND i.category2 = s.category2
```

If this isn't it, you might need to dump some sample data from each respective table of what you are trying to actually get.

Comment: Thank you very much for your lightning speed help, both. Both deserve the green validation but can't do this unfortunately so I gave it to the one who got less rep. points ;-) . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

multiply crit 1 by 1000 (or some other number-depending or size of numbers) and add to it Crit2

Use that formula in your `where` or `join`